# A war for what’s left of space

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, magic, science-fiction, warfare

My story is a space adventure, opera, and war with an advanced alien race going to war with each other using this [magic](https://docs.google.com/document/d/107fac0oChtUipvy6KxOz7ue4GBQE1SXt_sqj9ElHieg/edit) system the warring factions are the remnants of a Kardashev type 3. The biggest faction wishes to remove users of the magic system (they use it too) due to its Adverse effects on the universe. The other faction is for the free use of the magic system. But as I was worldbuilding, I realized I had no idea what warfare looks like in my setting or how to incorporate the magic system into battles.

Do you have any idea how the magic system can be integrated into battles in a space adventure, opera, and war story that involves advanced alien races? I am having difficulty envisioning what warfare would entail in my setting and require your input. Your prompt response would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This would be the third time that you've asked this question, it's not getting any better. We don't do "fishing for ideas" here. Please, please read and understand the [help]'s section about [on-topic questions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and stop trying to bypass the system.

Comment: I apologize if my previous comment sounded impatient, but there are rules on the site that we're all expected to adhere to, no matter how frustrating they might be (I could rant for hours about my personal frustrations, but I won't). I think I understand what you might be trying to achieve here, and we can all get behind you in that, but be patient with our ways.

Comment: Draft 85 - It’s ok thanks for the advice. I’m just trying to Formulate what It all looks like but I can’t quite get there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Work from what you have already imagined.**

In the linked description you describe 5 schools of magic.

> Schools of Evocation, Schools of Illusion, Schools of Enchantments,
> Schools of Divination, Schools of Abjuration.

I am thinking of your story told from the perspective of an individual who has comrades, Percy Jackson style.  Or maybe it is a comic book or manga - Teen Titans or Blue Exorcist style.

A battle team could incorporate 1 or 2 individuals from each school.  Each would bring their arts to the battle.  Some teams might really be like 5 solo acts which would be a good place to start.  I am thinking of newbie superhero teams where each one is a showboat solo act and they don't really know how to team up.    Some teams will work in concert to achieve combinatorial effects which will be exciting and new.

You might also have nonmagical ways to fight, which might be used by your big group that is opposed to magic.  Perhaps they have proudly nonmagical warriors who despite this (or because of it) are very bad of ass.

You have a world and now you need to set a story in your world.  I have imagined a way to do that because that mode of story is familiar and you could use serial engagements to show off your magic system and also grow your characters as people who will engage the readers.  All fight and no character development makes a dull story.

Unless you are me.  I am fine with all fight if they are cool fights!